# Supabase sign in with magic link not calling onAuthStateChange

Tags: supabase

I'm using react native and supabase

I call

```
await supabase.auth.signInWithOtp({
        email: email,
        options: {
          emailRedirectTo: 'myURL',
        },
      })
```

and this successfully sends the user an email.

the user clicks the email. I can see that the user is created in the supabase dashboard and email is verified

however in my app supabase.auth.onAuthStateChange method is never fired

also upon returning to the app I try and call await supabase.auth.getUser() but I get this:

{"data":{"user":null},"error":{"name":"AuthApiError","message":"invalid claim: missing sub claim","status":401}}

so not sure whats going on. Again the user is created in the supabase dashboard. They click the link in the email, it opens my app. i just get no call back

Comment: Hey @MobileMon,

Thanks for patiently waiting. Could we trouble you to reach out to Supabase Support at: https://app.supabase.com/support/new? Also, quick sanity check: are you using the React Native options: https://supabase.com/docs/reference/javascript/initializing for the client?

Comment: I solved it but the solution was not trivial nor documented anywhere. See my answer @JoelLee

Answer (score 2):

The solution was to set up deep linking on react native

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/deep-linking/

Then listen for the link opening, parse the link, and manually set the session based on what was parsed

```
useEffect(() => {
  const handleUrlRedirect = async (url) => {
    console.log('Received URL:', url);
    if (!url) return;
  
    // Extract the part after the '#'
    const fragment = url.split('#')[1];
    if (!fragment) return;
  
    // Convert the fragment into an object
    const params = new URLSearchParams(fragment);
    const access_token = params.get('access_token');
    const refresh_token = params.get('refresh_token');
  
    if (
      typeof access_token !== 'string' ||
      typeof refresh_token !== 'string'
    ) {
      console.log('An Error occurred. Email links are only valid for 1 click. Try requesting another link.')

      return;
    }
  
    try {

      supabase.auth.onAuthStateChange((event, session) => {
        console.log(event, session)
      })

       var data = await supabase.auth.setSession({
        access_token,
        refresh_token,
      });

    } catch (e) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  };

  Linking.getInitialURL().then((url) => {
    handleUrlRedirect(url);
  });

  const subscription = Linking.addEventListener('url', ({ url }) => {
    handleUrlRedirect(url);
  });

  return () => {
    subscription.remove();
  };
}, []);
```

Comment: Hi @MobileMon, I'm implementing this on react native too, I have deep linking setup and working fine, but the thing is that when I click on the magic link it never attemps to call the redirect url, instead I see an error on the browser "Verify requires a verification type"... Did you ever see this error? If so how did you fix it?

Comment: I found the issue, I was passing the url of the magic link to the emulator without wrapping it with "" so it was receiving the entire url.